# Дубликаты пакетов при пинге соседних систем

Tags: windows, сеть, virtualbox, xubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Имеются две виртуальные машины (Virtual Box) на Xubuntu с именами Client и Server, а так же хостовая система на Windows 8.1. 
Требовалось создать локальную сеть с сохранением доступа к сети Интернет (при условии, что хостовая система могла пинговать обе виртуальные машины). Выбор пал на Виртуальный адаптер хоста, которому был разрешен общий доступ к Интернету.

Собственно, виртуальный адаптер хоста получил IP 192.168.137.1. Исходя из этого, машине Server был присвоен статический адрес - 192.168.137.10, машине Client - 192.168.137.11.

Все работает прекрасно, кроме одного: при пинге одной виртуальной машины другой появляются дубликаты пакетов (см. скриншот)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему? Ниже прикрепляю скриншоты с настройками сети.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Сетевой мост` пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata Конечно, не подходит, так как мне нужна независимость от IP адреса внешнего роутера

Comment: Можно воткнуть сетевой мост и всё равно прохардкорить ip внутри виртуалок.

Comment: @donRumata И как сделать так, если у меня каждый раз будет меняться роутер, который раздает интернет, соответственно и ip-aдреса у всех его интерфейсов?

Comment: Ну т.е. будет менять адрес шлюза по умолчанию?

Comment: @donRumata Верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу, интернет лучше получать по другому адаптеру, настроенному на NAT.